# Bootstrap Modal Fixed Header scrolling in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have trouble getting the scroll bar(overflow-y: auto) to work on mobile devices and on phonegap.
Can any one help me? Thanks in advance!

Below is my jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/810hpkre/2/

```
.modal-body {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 125px);
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```